# Flatten multiple arrays with uneven lengths in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to flatten arrays in different columns with different lengths without duplicating the results.

For example (using standard SQL):

```
WITH
  x AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY[1,
    2,
    3] AS a,
    ARRAY[1,
    2] AS b)
SELECT
  a,
  b
FROM
  x,
  x.a,
  x.b
```

Produces:

```
+-----++-----+
| a   |   b  |
+-----++-----+
|   1 |   1  |
|   1 |   2  |
|   2 |   1  |
|   2 |   2  |
|   3 |   1  |
|   3 |   2  |
+-----++-----+
```

It should look like this:

```
+-----++-----+
| a   |   b  |
+-----++-----+
|   1 |   1  |
|   2 |   2  |
|   3 | null |
+-----++-----+
```

Comment: `MySQL <> google-bigquery`..

Comment: Looks like you are missing group by to get desired results

Comment: @TamirKlein - Could you provide an example?

Comment: Also i advice to remove the `sql` tag as `google-bigquery` deviate on some basic ANSI/ISO SQL syntax alot which is the sql tag about on this website. As the ANSI/ISO comma join syntax `FROM
  x,
  x.a,
  x.b` is a `UNION ALL` in `google-bigquery` instead of a `CROSS JOIN` which i believe was in legacy mode

Comment: @RaymondNijland - cross join produces the same result. Could you provide an example to illustrate your point?

Comment: *"cross join produces the same result"* Good then you run it in Standard SQL, then you can "ignore" mine comments

Comment: *"Could you provide an example to illustrate your point? – "* `from_body:
    {
      from_item [, ...] |  # Warning: Comma means UNION ALL here`  it's in the [manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) search on "Query grammar"

Comment: @RaymondNijland - The example is in the question. Please paste the SQL into BigQuery and hit run to reproduce the example in the question.

Comment: *"The example is in the question."* like i said you can "ignore" mine comment about legacy SQL (Where comma join in `FROM `means `UNION ALL`) and Standard SQL (Where comma join in `FROM` means `CROSS JOIN`) in google biggquery as it was not clear in which mode you are running the query as you was using the old ANSI/ISO comma join syntax..  Which ideally you should avoid to use annyway and use implict join syntax like @GordonLinoff  answer as his query is correct and should give the correct results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM x LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(x.a) a left join
     unnest(x.b) b 
     ON a = b;
```

Comment: This works really well. How would you add more columns beyond "a" and "b"? Let's say you had 2 more nested columns. How would you do your join? Initially, an "and" statement made sense ("... a = b and b = c") but it just duplicated "a" and "b". Any thoughts?

Comment: @ethanenglish . . . You can keep adding additional `unnest()`s.  If you cannot get it to work, you should ask another question.

Comment: I just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586399/join-uneven-arrays-from-many-columns-and-avoid-duplicates-in-bigquery :)