# Join uneven arrays from many columns and avoid duplicates in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584231/flatten-multiple-arrays-with-uneven-lengths-in-bigquery) that I thought abstracted my problem sufficiently but unfortunately, it did not.

I have a table of nested arrays, the first column is an int. I can join two arrays without duplication (as answered in my previous question) but I'm unsure how to do it with more than two.

Here is the table (in StandardSQL):

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS col1,
    ARRAY[1, 2 ] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4] AS col4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 AS col1, 
    ARRAY[1, 2, 2] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4] AS col4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    3 AS col1,
    ARRAY[2, 2 ] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4] AS col4
    )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a
```

Produces:

```
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
| col1   |   col2  |   col3  |   col4  |
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
|   1    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|        |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|        |         |   3     |   3     |
|        |         |         |   4     |
|   2    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|        |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|        |         |   3     |   3     |
|        |         |         |   4     |
|   3    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|        |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|        |         |   3     |   3     |
|        |         |         |   4     |
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
```

But what I'm looking for is this:

```
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
| col1   |   col2  |   col3  |   col4  |
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
|   1    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|  null  |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|  null  |  null   |   3     |   3     |
|  null  |  null   |  null   |   4     |
|   2    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|  null  |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|  null  |  null   |   3     |   3     |
|  null  |  null   |  null   |   4     |
|   3    |   1     |   1     |   1     |
|  null  |   2     |   2     |   2     |
|  null  |  null   |   3     |   3     |
|  null  |  null   |  null   |   4     |
+-------++--------++--------++---------+
```

Here is how I'm unnesting the many columns:

```
SELECT
  col1,
  _col2,
  _col3
FROM
  a left join 
  unnest(col2) as _col2 
  left join unnest(col3) as _col3
```

Producing this table:

```
+-------++--------++--------+
| col1   |   col2  |   col3 |
+-------++--------++--------+
|   1    |   1     |   1    |
|   1    |   1     |   2    |
|   1    |   1     |   3    |
|   1    |   2     |   1    |
|   1    |   2     |   2    |
|   1    |   2     |   3    |
|   2    |   1     |   1    |
|   2    |   1     |   2    |
|   2    |   1     |   3    |
|   2    |   2     |   1    |
|   2    |   2     |   2    |
|   2    |   2     |   3    |
...
...
...
+-------++--------++--------++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand how your results relate to the input data.  The results for all the `col1` values are exactly the same, but the inputs are different.

That said, I can interpret this as an extension of your previous question.  This may be what you want:

```
SELECT a.col1, c2, c3, c4
FROM (select a.*,
             (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT c) cs
              from unnest(array_concat( col2, col3, col4)) c
             ) cs
      from a 
     ) a cross join
     unnest(cs) c left join      
     unnest(a.col2) c2
     on c2 = c left join
     unnest(a.col3) c3
     on c3 = c left join
     unnest(a.col4) c4
     on c4 = c;
```

The initial subquery for `a` generates all the values in the arrays.  This is then used for a `left join`.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I wasn't understanding your implementation from the other question. You join each nest on c. Damn, thank you!

Comment: Would you take the same approach if the data was a little more inconsistent? For instance: ```WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS col1,
    ARRAY[1, 1,1,1,1,2 ] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4] AS col4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    2 AS col1, 
    ARRAY[ ] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 2,3,3, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[1, 3, 4] AS col4
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    3 AS col1,
    ARRAY[2, 2 ] AS col2,
    ARRAY[1, 3] AS col3,
    ARRAY[ 3, 4] AS col4
    )```

Comment: @ethanenglish . . . I would ask if it works.  This approach essentially does a `full join`, but that is not allowed with `unnest()`.

Comment: It does partially. There are duplicate rows and I'm unclear why. I'm still trying to unpack your strategy so I can use it to solve new problems but it's taking me a min.

Comment: @ethanenglish . . . You have duplicates in the arrays, so I would expect duplicates in the results.  You might want to ask another question.